# Create an excel file using xlsxwriter and save the excel file into PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, xlsxwriter

I manage to create many excel files by extracting the relevant data from MySQL tables and populating these data into Excel using Xlsxwriter. The number of created Excel files may exceed 100s at the point of data generation, and I need each excel file to be converted into PDF before I email out the files.

Manually converting each Excel file takes a few minutes, but just imagine doing for hundreds of files. I want to avoid using com32 or comtypes, and just through Xlsxwriter or VBA to get the conversion done. I have written some codes for Xlsxwriter, but somehow, this didn't work. Can someone advise, please. Thanks.

```
VBA_worksheet=current_workbook.add_worksheet()
current_workbook.add_vba_project('printPDF')
VBA_worksheet.write_formula('A1', 'ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF')
VBA_worksheet.activate()
VBA_worksheet.hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you supplied looks like you are trying to execute a VBA macro from XlsxWriter. If so that won't work.

It is possible to add VBA macros and functions to XlsxWriter files but only Excel can execute them.

In order to convert the xlsx files to PDF you will have to automate Excel or perhaps find some third party app that can do it.

Comment: Thanks JMC, I tried using Win32com and ComTypes. Somehow, I couldn't get the modules to work, and I have no idea why. Currently, I am executing Python on Windows, but later, we have to move the OS to Debian Jessie, and I was told that Win32com and Comtypes will not work. So, I need some advices. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you will need to look for some tool that converts xlsx files to PDF on Linux. I'm not aware of any such tool but that doesn't mean there isn't one.